# Google Cloud API: Invalid value for field 'machineType': 'f1-micro'. The URL is malformed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can't set the machine type for my stopped instance in Javascript. I thought I was sending it wrong but then went in the API playground to try it automatically and it still gives the same error.

The playground is there:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setMachineType

Machine types are there (I tried multiple types):
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setMachineType), machine type is a partial URL that includes the zone, e.g. `zones/us-west1-c/machineTypes/f1-micro`

Comment: Hahaha! I litterally just found that out while looking in other things and you must include the full url with google APIS. Good timing thanks ;)